# Where can I find Win SDK standalone installer for Windows 2008 R2

Tags: sdk

Where can I find Win SDK standalone installer for Windows 2008 R2? Or if other OS SDK is compatible to Win2008, where can I find it.

I need it for MSVS2005 on Win2008.

Comment: Why would you need that specific version? It's the first [hit on google](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11310). Also, depending on it, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247583/vs2005-and-windows-sdk-7-1).

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time it was just fair and all to shun OP for being *blind*, but nowadays it really is hard to find this

The [web installer](https://web.archive.org/web/20160706051257/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11310) cannot connect to the server, and [the ISO](https://web.archive.org/web/20081203032123/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en) is no more too. Googling `6.0.6001.18000.367-KRMSDK_EN.iso` on the web should help.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (ISO)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115186/what-sdk-version-to-download) to select correct file to download.